# Browser based application with possible future as web application

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, vb6-migration, browser-based

I am working to migrate an old VB6 Forms application to a browser based application, and need some input on a few options. The application needs to be able to be distributed via email, run on the client's computer (completely local) without access to the Internet, and have the ability to someday be converted to a full functioning web application (hosted instead of local) that would no longer require email distribution.

- Normal .Net web application (C#).

  - would this require IIS to be set up?
- Embed .Net WinForm in browser using WPF

  - like with [this codeproject example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31429/Embedding-a-NET-WinForms-Application-in-an-Interne)
- WPF Browser Application

  - This seems like it could be deployed and executed locally, but can it be migrated to a web app later on?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer all depends on your definition of "without access to the internet". If it means you have intranet access then have you considered [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the deployment mechanism? It seems to meet your requirements.

You could use either WinForms or fully fledged WPF for a rich client. However, using WPF carefully with regard to libraries used and the system permissions required will give you the ability to later port it to a Silverlight browser hosted rich application.

Regarding your other questions:

- A normal .net web application (ASP.NET) will require an IIS server out there somewhere and users to have access to that server.
- In your example showing embedded WinForms using WPF, you might as well just use WPF/Silverlight...
- WPF browser applications are deployed to web servers but executed on the client machine. Therefore it wouldn't readily "migrate to a web app later on".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with regards to Internet access. The app will need to be used at times when there is not an internet connection. (I know this seems to render the possibility of a webapp void, but mobile hotspots would then be used.) ClickOnce was considered, but we want to go ahead and use a browser implimentation so that later on we wont have to restrict the user base to Windows.

Comment: So a WPF browser application could not be executed offline?

Comment: As per http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/28/comparing-wpf-applications-and-xbap-whats-the-difference/ it looks like you need to have access to the activation URL.

Comment: Ok. So creating a regular WPF application (not an XBAP) seems like my best option since it can be ported to Silverlight. Thanks for all the help!